# variable value not being passed to other view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to just pass one value from one view controller to another, but it is appearing as nil in the second view controller.

Below is the code that is setting the value for the variable, which is setting the value of the 2nd view control variable as well:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestChat") as! TestChat 
   let user2Name = name[indexPath.row]
            let user2Info = ref.child("Users").child((myuser?.uid)!).child("Contacts")
            user2Info.observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

                let enumerator = snapshot.children
                while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {

                    print(String(describing: rest.value))
                    if((rest.childSnapshot(forPath: "/Name").value as! String) == user2Name) {
                        //this means that it has iterated to the correct user
                        self.user2cred = String(rest.key)
                        print(self.user2cred as! String)

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //below sets the value of numbers on the next view controller
                            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestChat") as! TestChat
                            print("this should be the credentials")
                            print(self.user2cred!)
                            vc.otherUserID = self.user2cred
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("doing nothing doing nothing")
                        //do NOTHING this is the wrong user being iterated on
                    }
                }
            })
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

second view controller is as shown:

```
class TestChat: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SBDConnectionDelegate, SBDChannelDelegate {

    var otherUserID: String?
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
print(self.otherUserID)
}
```

The value being printed directly before the assigning of the value of the second view controller prints what it should, but when the value is printed in the second view controller is prints "nil"

Comment: How exactly are you showing the `TestChat`?

Comment: How you pushed to secondViewController?

Comment: As the other suggest: We guess that the one presented and the one where you set the `user2cred` are not the same. Simply check the adress of each one (in `viewDidLoad()`, do `print("addressInViewDidLoad: %p", self)`, and after `vc.otherUserID = self.user2cred` do `print("address in closure: %p", vc)`

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani I am using the following code to segue: `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Drew - *where* are you calling `self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`?

Comment: @DonMag right after the end of the firebase snapshot

Comment: @Drew Add that line into you sample code. It's unclear if it's done correctly, we can't guess.

Comment: @Larme just added it to the code

Comment: Firstly that's not the same object :`self.present(vc...)` where `vc` is the one at the beginning of the method. Also, `self.user2cred = String(rest.key)` is called way after because the call of FireBase is async.